# How to configure ADSL connection using bash?

Tags: bash, debian, networking, dsl

I know it's possible to configure the modem to automatically connect the internet using a browser, but I want to do it using bash.

I would like the network to automatically connect when the system boots.

I have a ADSL2 router/modem and I'm using the Debian 6 Squeeze.

Comment: Does your router have a command line interface if you ssh to it? (You might need to enable that in the browser first.) This is a modem+router connected to the computer over Ethernet/wifi, right?

Comment: @Gilles Yes I have a Modem(ADSL2)+Router connected to the computer over Ethernet

Comment: @Gilles I will check if there is an option on the browser graphical interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is possible but how to depends on your router interface.

Many router can be configured via [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) or [snmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snmp) protocol. It'd be easy to find some command-line client for these protocols (e.g. [MiniUPnP](http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/), [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/)).

If your router does not support any of these well known protocols, you could try to emulate a browser via some command line tool as [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or curl. E.g. I can reboot my [ipfire](http://www.ipfire.org/) router using: `wget --user=USER --password=PASS https://myrouterip:444/cgi-bin/index.cgi?ACTION=Reboot`